# I'm making website but that shows Uncaught Type Error I can't able to get what is it

Tags: javascript

I'm making stack clone but getting 2 errors

1. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'result') in Navbar.js
2. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data') in Homebar.js

I'm not able to get how to solve this issue
I want to get Home page But just get Blank page with upper 2 Errors in console.log

## This is my Homebar.js

```
import React from "react";

import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import QuestionList from "./QuestionList";
import "./Homebar";
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function Homebar() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const user = 1;
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const questionsList = useSelector((state) => state.questionsReducer);
  // console.log(questionsList)
  // var questionsList = [{
  //     _id: 1,
  //     upVotes: 3,
  //     downVotes: 2,
  //     noOfAnswers: 2,
  //     questionTitle: "What is a function?",
  //     questionBody: "It meant to be",
  //     questionTags: ["java", "node js", "react js", "mongo db", "express js"],
  //     userPosted: "mano",
  //     userId: 1,
  //     askedOn: "jan 1",
  //     answer: [{
  //         answerBody: "Answer",
  //         userAnswered: 'kumar',
  //         answeredOn: "jan 2",
  //         userId: 2,
  //     }]
  // },{
  //     _id: 2,
  //     upVotes: 3,
  //     downVotes: 2,
  //     noOfAnswers: 0,
  //     questionTitle: "What is a function?",
  //     questionBody: "It meant to be",
  //     questionTags: ["javascript", "R", "python"],
  //     userPosted: "mano",
  //     askedOn: "jan 1",
  //     userId: 1,
  //     answer: [{
  //         answerBody: "Answer",
  //         userAnswered: 'kumar',
  //         answeredOn: "jan 2",
  //         userId: 2,
  //     }]
  // },{
  //     _id: 3,
  //     upVotes: 3,
  //     downVotes: 2,
  //     noOfAnswers: 0,
  //     questionTitle: "What is a function?",
  //     questionBody: "It meant to be",
  //     questionTags: ["javascript", "R", "python"],
  //     userPosted: "mano",
  //     askedOn: "jan 1",
  //     userId: 1,
  //     answer: [{
  //         answerBody: "Answer",
  //         userAnswered: 'kumar',
  //         answeredOn: "jan 2",
  //         userId: 2,
  //     }]
  // }]

  const checkAuth = () => {
    if (user === null) {
      alert("login or signup to ask a question");
      navigate("/Auth");
    } else {
      navigate("/AskQuestion");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="main-bar">
      <div className="main-bar-header">
        {location.pathname === "/" ? (
          <h1>Top Questions</h1>
        ) : (
          <h1>All Questions</h1>
        )}
        <button onClick={checkAuth} className="ask-btn">
          Ask Question
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        {questionsList.data === null ? (
          <h1>Loading...</h1>
        ) : (
          <>
            <p>{questionsList.data.length} questions</p>
            <QuestionList questionsList={questionsList.data} />
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>

  );
}

export default Homebar;
```

## And Now this is Navbar.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import SearchIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Search";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import decode from "jwt-decode";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
import "./Navbar.css";
import { setCurrentUser } from "../../Actions/CurrentUser";
import Avatar from "../Avatar/Avatar";

function Navbar() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  var User = useSelector((state) => state.currentUserReducer);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleLogout = () => {
    dispatch({ type: "LOGOUT" });
    navigate("/");
    dispatch(setCurrentUser(null));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = User?.token;
    if (token) {
      const decodedToken = decode(token);
      if (decodedToken.exp * 1000 < new Date().getTime()) {
        handleLogout();
      }
    }
    dispatch(setCurrentUser(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Profile"))));
  }, [User?.token, dispatch]);

  return (
    <nav>
      <div className="nav">
        <Link to="/">
          <div className="logo">
            <img
              src="https://www.vectorlogo.zone/logos/stackoverflow/stackoverflow-official.svg"
              alt="logo"
            />
          </div>
        </Link>
        <div className="about">
          <p>About</p>
        </div>
        <div className="Products">
          <p>Products</p>
        </div>
        <div className="For-teams">
          <p>For Teams</p>
        </div>
        <div className="auth">
          <div className="search">
            <SearchIcon />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
          </div>
          {User === null ? (
            <></>
          ) : (
            <>
              <div className="login">
                <Link to="/auth">
                  <Button
                    style={{
                      height: "2rem",
                      background: " hsl(205,46%,92%)",
                      color: "#2C5877",
                      fontSize: "0.813rem",
                      textTransform: "capitalize",
                      border: "0.063rem solid #7AA7C7",
                      top: "0.5rem",
                      marginLeft: "10px",
                      textDecoration: "none",
                    }}
                  >
                    Login
                  </Button>
                </Link>{" "}
                :
                <Avatar
                  backgroundColor="#009dff"
                  px="10px"
                  py="7px"
                  borderRadius="50%"
                  color="white"
                >
                  <Link
                    to={`/Users/${User?.result?._id}`}
                    style={{ color: "white", textDecoration: "none" }}
                  >
                    {User.result.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}
                  </Link>
                </Avatar>
                <button className="nav-item nav-links" onClick={handleLogout}>
                  Log out
                </button>
              </div>
              <Link to="/auth">
                <div className="signup">
                  <Button
                    style={{
                      height: "2rem",
                      background: " #0074CC",
                      color: "white",
                      fontSize: "0.813rem",
                      textTransform: "capitalize",
                      top: "0.5rem",
                      marginLeft: "10px",
                      textDecoration: "none",
                    }}
                  >
                    Sign Up
                  </Button>
                </div>
              </Link>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

**Please help in solving .data and .result problem to complete the code**

Comment: questionsList has no data to read because you commented out the values that you assigned to it. That is error 2.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and [edit] your question to include what research you've done into these errors. For instance, there is [How to solve TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getName')](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74103470/215552)

Comment: but i thought i asked what i need and my problem is solved in that error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to access a property on an `object`, and the object is probably `null` or `undefined`.

You can try to use the optional chaining operator.

> The optional chaining operator (?.) accesses an object's property or
> calls a function. If the object is undefined or null, it returns
> undefined instead of throwing an error.

Example from your Homebar code:

```
  <div>
    {!questionsList?.data ? (
      <h1>Loading...</h1>
    ) : (
      <>
        <p>{questionsList?.data?.length} questions</p>
        <QuestionList questionsList={questionsList?.data} />
      </>
    )}
  </div>
```

I can see that you are using this in NavBar but not everywhere, which is what causes the error. Update the line where you are reading User.result to use this as well.

```
{User?.result.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}
```

Comment: than what should i do about navbar

Comment: It would help if you did the same thing in navbar. I have updated the answer

Comment: Fralle how can I connect you personally for my other code problems here they are saying I can't ask more questions